# Java : How do I call a method in a different class that extends Thread and is a part of a Thread Array from my main class?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple main class which listens on a socket, and adds (networked) clients to an array of Threads as they join in ( like a server listening for new chat clients , and adding each client as a thread , and maintaining the list of threads as an array).

Other things are working, these are the code lines where the server listens and adds a new client to an array of threads called thdRunningClientsPool[]

```
//add a new ClientHandler type object( ClientHandler class extends Thread) to my Thread Array
public void run() {
............
 thdRunningClientsPool[intRunningClients]= new 
                   Thread( new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
 thdRunningClientsPool[intRunningClients].start();
```

Now, The ClientHandler class has a method
    void SendMessage(string Message)

How do I send a message using this SendMessage method after a new client is added? When I use this

```
thdRunningClientsPool[intRunningClients].SendMessage("hi");
```

The SendMessage method is not found. Java is treating thdRunningClientsPool(intRunningClients) as a thread, not as a object of ClientHandler class and so I can't acces my SendMessage method.

How can I fix this? Any advice greatly appreciated :)
THxxx

Comment: What is `ClientHandler`? Does it extend Thread or does it implement Runnable? Any reasons why you don't use one of the built-in thread pools?

Answer (score 4):

First, general advice: use `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`. Will save you a lot of headaches down the road.

As for your question, you can't call `sendMessage` on the `Thread` instance that was passed your instance as an argument. You must change the code to hold references to your `ClientHandler`s; you don't really need the array of outer `Thread` instances. Just start them and let go of them.

You should also reconsider your choice to start all those threads on your own, this is usually a bad idea because it wastes system resources. However, redesigning that aspect of your code is beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: thx Marko. I will change it to Runnable later, as it isn't a big project. As per your answer, if I hold references to the ClientHandler class, how do i actually do it( I know it sounds like a Noob question)... I'll HAVE TO use either a arraylist, list, vector, or is there anothing option? :) thx

Comment: Stay with the array, if you wish, just make it an array of `ClientHandler`. Then the line from your question will compile and run as you intend it to.

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!! So simple. I should have just made the thdRunningClientsPool a ClientHandler type array to start with. I am still having problems with sending messages but that is definitely some other logical error and I should be able to fix that myself later. May Gods of Java bring you a year free of Null-pointer exceptions Marko!

Comment: Too late, I've already had about a dozen of those since New Year :))